# This package indirectly depends on multiple versions... prevents use of ghci

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, ghci

The same (basically) question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301122/haskell-cabal-package-indirectly-depends-on-multiple-versions-of-the-same-pack) but I'm looking for a specific answer to my current question (as opposed to the general answer found in the link).

I have a problem using Haskell and cabal, in that, my project depends on two different versions of `bytestring`. The project still runs - but it prevents me from using `ghci`, which kind of sucks.

Here is the error message:

```
 |package. This is highly likely to cause a compile failure.
 |package text-0.11.3.1 requires bytestring-0.10.0.2
 |package stb-image-0.2.1 requires bytestring-0.10.0.2
 |package parsec-3.1.5 requires bytestring-0.10.0.2
 |package bitmap-0.0.2 requires bytestring-0.10.0.2
 |package zlib-0.5.4.1 requires bytestring-0.10.4.0
 |package unix-2.7.0.0 requires bytestring-0.10.4.0
 |package repa-3.2.3.3 requires bytestring-0.10.4.0
 |package daimyo-0.1.0.0 requires bytestring-0.10.4.0
 |package binary-0.7.1.0 requires bytestring-0.10.4.0
 |package JuicyPixels-repa-0.7 requires bytestring-0.10.4.0
 |package JuicyPixels-3.1.3.2 requires bytestring-0.10.4.0
```

I can't isolate my packages down to one version of `bytestring`, since I need both `parsec` and `JuicyPixels-repa`.

ghci throws the error

```
GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
    _fps_count
```

regarding the `bytestring` package.

Is there any way that I can use `ghci` in spite of this?

Comment: You could download the source for the package, change the `.cabal` file to use the appropriate version of `bytestring`, then install it from source that way.

Comment: @bheklilr That's icky. :D But it would have been my last resort, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume [daimyo](https://github.com/mattgallivan/daimyo) is your project. That being so, your problem is that the version constraints in your [cabal file](https://github.com/mattgallivan/daimyo/blob/2235e419d56287cf668b1feda7e26ba83d909396/daimyo.cabal) are too strict. In particular, the `bytestring` constraint should be `bytestring == 0.10.*`, so that the package works with `bytestring-0.10.0.2`, which probably came with your Haskell Platform or equivalent. There should be no incompatibilities, as according to the [package versioning policy](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Package_versioning_policy) the two first parts of the version being equal implies the APIs are compatible.

As for actually making it work, you will have to unregister the new `bytestring` package (`ghc-pkg unregister bytestring-0.10.4.0`) and all packages that depend on it, and then reinstall those packages (except `bytestring` of course). After that, you can minimize the frequency of such headaches by using Cabal 1.18 (`cabal install cabal-install` if you don't have it) and its [sandboxes](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html).